# Increase Azure FREB Log Size

Tags: logging, azure

I am trying to diagnose an internal server error on an Azure Web App. I've enabled FREB (aka FRT) logging on the site, but the log associated with the 500 status code ends with event name "LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE_TRUNCATE". It seems like my logs are being truncated and I'm therefore not seeing the actual cause of the 500 error. I can't seem to find any way to increase this file size. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to https://***yourwebsite***.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole .

And run;

```
appcmd set config /section:sites -siteDefaults.traceFailedRequestsLogging.maxLogFileSizeKB:1024
```

It's 512KB by default, this changes it to 1024KB.

Comment: When I try to run the command I receive this error: 
`'appcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: You should run a "cd D:\Windows\System32\inetsrv" first. Appcmd.exe was in that folder if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: when I run this I get an "Access is denied." message. Full message: Applied configuration changes to section "system.applicationHost/sites" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
ERROR ( hresult:80070005, message:Failed to commit configuration changes.  

Access is denied.

 )